# Read Counter value From CLICK PLC to python using pymodbus with RS232 port

Tags: python, serial-port, modbus, plc, pymodbus

Very New to this but I would essentially like to read my counter value from my CLICK PLC into my python.

My Click Series PLC only has a RS232 Port with Modbus protocal . Can I use pymodbus for this?

Is there another way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research. yes it is possible to use pymodbus.

RS 232 is an older serial communication protocol that can use Modbus ASCII and Modbus RTU software protocols(Binary).
pymodbus supports both these .
You just need to direct pymodbus to the com port your "Slave devices" are connected / daisy-chained to.

remember there can only be one master to 247 nodes.